# How do I make 2 DIV's with different heights reach the bottom of the page at the same time on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, scroll

I'm trying to make the *#content* and *#content-sidebar* DIV's of [**my Wordpress blog**](http://robt.info) reach the bottom and top of the page at the same time when scrolling to avoid having all the whitespace that currently exists.

I've been able to successfully replicate what I am trying to achieve in JFIDDLE with the following code -

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    1<br />
    2<br />
    3<br />
    4<br />
    5<br />
    6<br />
    7<br />
    8<br />
    9<br />
    10<br />
    11<br />
    12<br />
    13<br />
    14<br />
    15<br />
    16<br />
    17<br />
    18<br />
    19<br />
    20<br />
    21<br />
    22<br />
    23<br />
    24<br />
    25<br />
    26<br />
    27<br />
    28<br />
    29<br />
    30<br />
    31<br />
    32<br />
    33<br />
    34<br />
    35<br />
    36<br />
    END<br />
</div>
<div id="content-sidebar">
    1<br />
    2<br />
    3<br />
    4<br />
    5<br />
    6<br />
    7<br />
    8<br />
    9<br />
    END<br />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var doc = $(window);
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $("#content-sidebar").css('top', (calculateScrollSpeed()));
});

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    $("#content-sidebar").css('top', (calculateScrollSpeed()));
});

function calculateScrollSpeed() {
    var leftPaneHeight = $('#content').height();
    var rightPaneHeight = $('#content-sidebar').height();
    var browserHeight = $(window).height();
    var leftPaneScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log((browserHeight - rightPaneHeight) / (browserHeight - leftPaneHeight));
    return -$(window).scrollTop() * ((browserHeight - rightPaneHeight) / (browserHeight - leftPaneHeight));
}
});
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
float: left;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
width: 400px;
}

#content-sidebar {
margin-left: 400px;
position: fixed;
width: 400px;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/eBk5f/**

What I am trying to understand is, why is it that when I replicate this working, functional demonstration into the code of my Wordpress site, it doesn't function properly???

Is there some other code on my site overriding the code in the JFIDDLE???

I am currently auto-optimizing javascript files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors, I'm guessing you might have a "$ is not defined" error as Wordpress is in no-conflict mode by default.

Comment: I'm seeing one Uncaught TypeError but it isn't in the scroll script... could this be affecting it??

Comment: If you have an error, that's probably it, but you're not posting the error so it's impossible for me to tell ?

Answer (score 0):

[Adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) helped me answer this.

Because I am using Wordpress (which is in no-conflict mode), I simply replaced the '$' with 'jQuery'  in the script and resolved this issue.

THANKS